# I am trying to send map data from one page to other using routes in Flutter . and getting this Error

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

***Sending Code***

```dart
 Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home',arguments: {
      "main_value":main,
      "desc_value":description,
      "temp_value":temp,
      "humidity_value":humidity,
    });
```

***Receiving Code***

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map  info = *ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;*
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("HOME"),
        ),
```

This line getting an error

```
Map info = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

> A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.
> Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;` returns a type of `Object?` that can't be assigned directly to a Map, this is because `arguments` allow you to put any value in it, so you just need to cast it to the correct value

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map info = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;
    ...
}
```

it could also be useful to have a check before that, since `arguments` can contain anything!

you can use `is` for the check:

```
final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
if(arguments is Map) {
   //YOUR LOGIC
} else {
   //YOUR ALTERNATIVE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast `arguments`  to map like so:

```
Map<String, dynamic> info = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic >;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . it solved..

Comment: You're welcome...Kindly upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Map info = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

to this:

```
final info = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String,String>;
```

or, if you don't know value, use `Map<String,dynamic>`